# memory efficient way

Tags: go, testing, benchmarking

I have two examples of the similar program written on Go. Main aim of that code is sort map of structs using value in the struct.

Example with pointers

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type payload struct {
    data string
    value  float64
}

type container struct {
    counter int
    storage map[int]*payload
}

type payloadSlice []*payload

// Len is part of sort.Interface.
func (p payloadSlice) Len() int {
    return len(p)
}

// Swap is part of sort.Interface.
func (p payloadSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]
}

// Less is part of sort.Interface. We use count as the value to sort by
func (p payloadSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].value < p[j].value
}
func main() {
    name := "special_unique_name"
    var m = map[string]container{
        name: {counter: 10, storage: map[int]*payload{
            5: {data: "epsilon", value: 55},8: {data: "theta", value: 85},4: {data: "delta", value: 48},1: {data: "alpha", value: 14},10: {data: "kappa", value: 101},
            3: {data: "gamma", value: 31},6: {data: "zeta", value: 63},2: {data: "beta", value: 26},9: {data: "iota", value: 92},7: {data: "eta", value: 79},
        }},
    }
    s := make(payloadSlice, 0, len(m[name].storage))
    for _, v := range m[name].storage {
        s = append(s, v)
    }
    sort.Sort(s)

    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(name, v)
    }
}
```

Examples with values

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type payload struct {
    data string
    value  float64
}

type container struct {
    counter int
    storage map[int]payload
}

type payloadSlice []payload

// Len is part of sort.Interface.
func (p payloadSlice) Len() int {
    return len(p)
}

// Swap is part of sort.Interface.
func (p payloadSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]
}

// Less is part of sort.Interface. We use count as the value to sort by
func (p payloadSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].value < p[j].value
}
func main() {
    name := "special_unique_name"
    var m = map[string]container{
        name: {counter: 10, storage: map[int]payload{
            5: {data: "epsilon", value: 55},8: {data: "theta", value: 85},4: {data: "delta", value: 48},1: {data: "alpha", value: 14},10: {data: "kappa", value: 101},
            3: {data: "gamma", value: 31},6: {data: "zeta", value: 63},2: {data: "beta", value: 26},9: {data: "iota", value: 92},7: {data: "eta", value: 79},
        }},
    }
    s := make(payloadSlice, 0, len(m[name].storage))
    for _, v := range m[name].storage {
        s = append(s, v)
    }
    sort.Sort(s)

    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(name, v)
    }
}
```

I'd like to know 2 moments:

1. Which example will be memory-efficient? (I guess it's a pointer way)
2. How to measure performance of these examples, using test data with  with different number of structs inside the map? Can you help me with creating Benchmark?

I suppose the size of each struct in the map will vary from 1-2kB in average.

Comment: If by "memory-efficient", you mean using less memory, using pointer is not necessarily more efficient because you're adding 64bits (and a pointer dereference, but that's a time trade-off) on top of every value. Use the one that is most logical in your program, and profile if you have performance issues. (also, it doesn't matter how large your payload data is, your payload struct is always the same size)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to keep your questions to a single question, and include any relevant code *in the body of your question* rather than at an external link. Feel free to use external links to provide additional context.

Comment: JimB, I have no performance issues at all, I'm interesting in what approach is better, and moreover how to properly test it. I made a simple benchmark with golang "testing" package, but I can test code only with a predefined dataset which is quietly small, and I'd like to know how to test with more bigger dataset.

Comment: Start with the one that makes sense in the program, because in 99.9% of cases it doesn't matter otherwise. Every single `payload` struct is only 24 bytes on a 64bit system, so adding a pointer may be just as likely to slow things down. If you want to test with a bigger data set, you simply need a bigger data set, which usually comes with determining real world usage rather than guessing beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Memory-efficient" is a pretty broad term, and can mean a couple of very different things in a garbage-collected language like Go that has separate heap and stack:

- What uses the least memory?
- What creates the least GC pressure?

If you want to minimize the application's footprint, you *probably* want to use pointers any time that you use a value in multiple scopes (e.g. multiple functions). This reduces copying, but adds overhead equal to the pointer size (8 bytes on a 64-bit system).

If you want to minimize GC pressure, you *probably* want to use pointers only when you need pointer semantics, or the underlying values are quite large. A pointer forces the value onto the heap, which is subject to garbage collection, while a value can be kept on the stack, which is not (when the function returns, the stack is destroyed in its entirety, which is thread-safe and requires no reference tracking).

"GC pressure" is the idea that the more things are created and destroyed on the heap, the more work the garbage collector has to do, which takes processor time away from the real work your application is doing. Every time you allocate on the heap, if there isn't space for the new value, the garbage collector will try to free space by looking for values on the heap that are no longer needed. The more you allocate on the heap, the more often GC has to run, and the longer those runs will take.

To your second question, you can (and should!) measure performance of various approaches to your specific circumstance using the [benchmarking facility of the `testing` package](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks). Make sure you test with realistic data and operations; microbenchmarks or benchmarks using "dummy" data types are unlikely to yield data of any value. The documentation for that package, and countless blog posts and tutorials easily found by web search, should guide you in the right direction on how to write and use benchmarks in Go.

In your specific case, bear in mind that your data type is - as far as this question is concerned - smaller than you think: 24 bytes on a 64-bit system, *regardless of the length of the string*. Why? Because a `string`, internally, is a struct containing an `int` for the length and a pointer to the underlying bytes. When you're trying to optimize for memory use, remember that strings, slices (but not arrays!), and maps are all very small structs containing pointers to their underlying data.

**And most importantly**: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. You should be writing code for two things: functionality, and readability. Use pointer semantics when they deliver the functionality you need, and make intuitive sense to use. If you **measure** a resource problem (CPU or memory), *then* you should profile your application to find the sources of the problem, prioritize them, and optimize them.

***Until you have measured and profiled a performance problem, you do not have a performance problem.***